# ADO.NET Insert Min Value into SQL Server 2008 Date column crashes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, date

I'm trying to do the following:

```
using (var tx = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
{
 var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
 command.Transaction = tx;
 command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TryDate([MyDate]) VALUES(@p0)";
 var dateParam = command.CreateParameter();
 dateParam.ParameterName = "@p0";
 dateParam.DbType = DbType.Date;
 dateParam.Value = DateTime.MinValue.Date;
 command.Parameters.Add(dateParam);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 tx.Commit();
}
```

where the table has a SQL Server 2008 Date column. I can insert a value of '01/01/0001' into this via SQL Management Studio.

If I run the above on the ExecuteNonQuery I get a "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM." exception.

Why is this? The SQL Server Date field does indeed accept 01/01/0001.

Comment: Try `dateParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;` instead of `dateParam.DbType = DbType.Date;` - define and use the `SqlDbType` - that works for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
command.Transaction = tx;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TryDate([MyDate]) VALUES(@p0)";
SqlParameter dateParam = new SqlParameter();
dateParam.ParameterName = "@p0";
dateParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date;
dateParam.Value = DateTime.MinValue.Date;
command.Parameters.Add(dateParam);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Reflecting the SqlParameter code shows that there's a definite distinction between DbType.Date and SqlDbType.Date - I've not found the particular line of code in the Framework that results in the error - however, using SqlDbType.Date should definitely solve this.

Comment: Thanks Will A. I suspected this would be the answer but really don't get why the "generic" DbType Date would fail with a SQL Server error. Especially since there is a also a DateTime DbType that I'd expect to match up to the original SQL DateTime type that have always had this restriction.

Looks like a .NET bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says 
    Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

SQLServer DateTime columns have different min and max values than a dateTime variable in the CLR.

You may want to put logic in your program to protect the database from datetimes that are out of the SQLServer range.

Comment: I initially thought this was it to, but he's using the newer `DATE` datatype.  `DATE` and `DATETIME2` match the range of values allowed by the CLR.  His problem appears to be in the ADO.NET call, not in SQL Server.  His code must be inferring `DATETIME` instead of `DATE` somewhere.

Comment: Nope - using DbType.Date rather than SqlDbType.Date is breaking the code and restricting the range.

Answer (score 0):

*DbType.Date* is just an alias for *DbType.DateTime*, since it was conceived well before SQL Server 2008 had support for dates. You can see the whole story here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646183/wrong-code-in-sqlparameter-dbtype-set-property.

Short story: as answered by Will, you can use *SqlDbType.Date*, which is not an alias.