# Date column not being persisted for dates before the year 1753

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm trying to persist an entity using NHibernate, but my `DateTime?` property is not being persisted for dates before 1753. I'm aware of the fact that this is  `DATETIME`'s lower bound, but in this case my property is backed by a `DATE` column, which according to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.100).aspx) is capable of handling dates ranging `0001-01-01` through `9999-12-31`.

NHibernate inserts a `NULL` for the `DateOfBirth` column if I try to persist January 1st, 1752.

This occurred in a bigger project, but I've taken the time to create a small repro like this:

- I have SQL Server 2012 Express on my localhost, with a fresh database "NhTestDb";
- Create a new class library named "NHibernateTests" in Visual Studio 2012;
- Using NuGet add NHibernate (4.0.3.4000) and dependencies;
- Using NuGet add NUnit (2.6.4)
- Add the following hbm file as an embedded resource:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateTests" namespace="NHibernateTests">
    <class name="Person">
      <id name="Id">
        <generator class="native" />
      </id>
      <property name="Name" />
      <property name="DateOfBirth" type="Date" />
    </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
  ```
- Add the following code to a .cs file:

  ```csharp
  using System;
  using System.Reflection;
  using NHibernate;
  using NHibernate.Cfg;
  using NHibernate.Dialect;
  using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  namespace NHibernateTests
  {
      public class Person
      {
          public virtual int Id { get; set; }
          public virtual string Name { get; set; }
          public virtual DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
      }

      [TestFixture]
      public class Tests
      {
          private ISessionFactory factory;

          [TestFixtureSetUp]
          public void TestFixtureSetUp()
          {
              var configuration = new Configuration();

              configuration.DataBaseIntegration(db => 
              {
                  db.ConnectionString = @"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=NhTestDb";
                  db.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
              });

              configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
              configuration.CurrentSessionContext<NHibernate.Context.ThreadStaticSessionContext>();

              factory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

              using (var schemaCreationSession = factory.OpenSession())
              {
                  new SchemaExport(configuration).Execute(true, true, false, schemaCreationSession.Connection, Console.Out);
              }
          }

          [Test]
          public void Can_Persist_DateOfBirth()
          {
              var session = factory.OpenSession();

              var person = new Person {Name = "John", DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1752, 1, 1)};

              session.Save(person);
              session.Refresh(person);
              session.Dispose();

              Assert.That(person.Name, Is.EqualTo("John"));
              Assert.That(person.DateOfBirth, Is.EqualTo(new DateTime(1752, 1, 1)));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

And see the test fail because the DateOfBirth is actually `null`.

I've double checked using the debugger that `DateOfBirth` is in fact set to the correct value just before it's being saved.

I've double checked that the generated column is in fact a `Date`, and checked [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.100).aspx) that this type's range is big enough;

I've also checked that other properties *are* being persisted: see the NUnit test, which Asserts persistence of the `Name` property.

I've added log4net via NuGet and configured NHibernate to output formatted SQL, which is as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO Person (Name, DateOfBirth) 
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
-- @p0 = 'John' [Type: String (4000)],
-- @p1 = NULL [Type: DateTime (0)]
```

So it is in fact *NHibernate* that seems to give me trouble: it explicitly inserts `NULL`. I've double checked this by inserting a row manually with SSMS, which does accept `'16000101'` as a value.

Finally, I've re-run the test with `new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)`, which is persisted just fine.

Bottom line: how do I get NHibernate to persist pre-1753 dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5425610/419956), just about a duplicate I guess. In any case, [the answer there by @JimFennel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5505222/419956) was a solution for me too. Changing my property mapping to this...

```
<property name="DateOfBirth" type="DateTime2">
  <column name="DateOfBirth" sql-type="date" />
</property>
```

...solves my particular issue as well.

Comment: PS. Did want to post a solution here too for all the Googlers landing on my question, but marked it as 'community wiki' since I guess any rep should be given to @JimFennel by upvoting [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5505222/419956).